# Add class option in rich text editor in h2 tag

Tags: content-editor, richtext-editor

I added a class option in the rich text editor in the content tree.  The requirement is to add this class in `<h2>` tag.

[image: RTE CSS]

But it's adding a class in the `<span>` tag by default:

[image: RTE HTML]

The requirement is to add this class in `h2` tag. Is there any settings for that ?

Comment: I think the best option is to create a snippet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to add it under the Normal dropdown?
[image]

If so first check your RTE Profile, which is being used in the template. based on that.

1. Change the DB to Core
2. Navigate to path `/sitecore/system/Settings/HTML Editor Profiles/<Your Rich Text Profile From template>` change the h2 value and add `<h2 class="h2>`

[image]

Comment: I have tried it but it does not include class after adding in RTE, it just picks up html tag

Comment: @Vinesh , please check your RTE profile , there are 4-5 RTE Profiles , there might be a chance you made a change in the RTE profile which is not being used, I am pretty sure this will work , since I have implemented this

Comment: It worked, previously i was adding in different type of RTE